# (Android) Сохранение ArrayList в файл

Tags: android

У меня возникла проблема с записью ArrayList (который содержит объекты класса) в файл (с помощью сериализации ArrayList в Json-строку). По идее каждый раз при вызове setValue(...) должна происходить перезапись ArrayList в файл, но вместо этого в файл сохраняется только последнее записанное значение (затирая собой предыдущее). Помогите понять в чем проблема. Заранее спасибо.

```
public class Dictionary implements Parcelable {
private ArrayList<WordAndTranslation> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private Gson gson = new Gson();
private final String filepath = "dictionary.txt";

public ArrayList getArrayList(Context context)
{
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.openFileInput(filepath)));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String lines;
        while ((lines = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(lines + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WordAndTranslation>>(){}.getType();
        arrayList = new Gson().fromJson(stringBuilder.toString(), listType);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayList;
}

public void setValue(WordAndTranslation object, Context context)
{
    arrayList.add(object);
    try {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                context.openFileOutput(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
        String JsonArrayList = gson.toJson(arrayList);
        bufferedWriter.write(JsonArrayList);
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(this.arrayList);
}

public Dictionary() {
}

protected Dictionary(Parcel in) {
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<WordAndTranslation>();
    in.readList(this.arrayList, WordAndTranslation.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Dictionary> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Dictionary>() {
    @Override
    public Dictionary createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Dictionary(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Dictionary[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Dictionary[size];
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Данные не будут потеряны только в том случае, если **на этом же экземпляре** `Dictionary` ранее был вызван `getArrayList`, который взял из файла существующие данные, а только потом вызывать `setValue`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло